# Redux - Action is dispatched when not explicitly called

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm fairly new to Redux and am experiencing some behavior I don't quite understand.

1. I have another function `nextFiveDays` that calls the exact same action but this is fired with a button click. When the button is clicked, I do see the action.type is `UPDATE_DATE` dispatched and the store is updated.
2. In the function `nextFiveDays`, the action is dispatched even if the `updateDate` function is commented out. It seems `setState` still triggers the action to be dispatched. Why is that?

```
class SomeComponent {
    state = { date: new Date() }

    nextFiveDays = () => {
        let date = new Date(this.state.date);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);
        //updateDate(date); // Redux store action dispatch
        this.setState({ date });
    };

    prevFiveDays = () => {
        let date = new Date(this.state.date);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 5);
        //updateDate(date); // Redux store action dispatch
        this.setState({ date });
    };

    render() {
        const { date } = this.state

        return <SemanticDatepicker
                        value={new Date(date)}
                        date={new Date(date)}
                        onChange={(_, data: any) => {
                            this.setState({ date: data.value });
                            updateDate(data.value);
                        }}
                    />
                       <Button
                            onClick={this.prevFiveDays}
                        />
                        <Button
                            onClick={this.nextFiveDays}
                        />
    }
```

Comment: nextFiveDays - this function is not called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the `nextFiveDays` function, it will update the `date` state and will re-render the component.

You set the value of `SemanticDatePicker` with this `date` state value so it triggers `onChange` event.

You dispatch the action inside `onChange` event handler.

This is why the action is dispatched.

**Note:**

Redux Action can be tied into `props` of the component but nothing related to component's state.

**Solution:**

Currently, you are updating the component's state and redux store with same value.

You can remove your `date` state value and map the property from your store to the component props. (using `mapStateToProps`)

So just dispatching the action will persist your `date` value from your store to the component.

Comment: Sorry I edited some mistakes. The `retrieveData` has async/await but I forgot to `const { updateDate } = this.props`. The button is actually using `nextFiveDays`, that was a typo on my end.

Comment: your `updateDate` is still calling though you commented the code?

Comment: Yes. The action `UPDATE_DATE` is still dispatched. Either thru `updateDate` (if uncommented) and/or thru `setState`. I'm wondering if Redux store is tied to a component's state.

Comment: if would be good if you can add your whole component code

Comment: The component is pretty large so I've added everything related to the date dispatch action.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for clarifying the best practice data flow.